# javascript cant launch or return results from function

Tags: javascript, return, exec

I have this function that is supposed to return taxes, total and total before taxes of a choice in a select menu. This is the function:

var select = document.getElementById('entree');

```
select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  taxesrepas(select.value);
});

function taxesrepas(option) {
  var soustot = 0,
    taxes = 0,
    total = 0,
    soustot = 0;


  if (option == "spaghetti") {
    total += 9.62;
    taxes += 0.67;
    soustot += 8.95;
  }
  if (option == "lasagne") {
    total += 10.70;
    taxes += 0.75;
    soustot += 9.95;
  }

  if (option == "salade") {
    total += 6.30;
    taxes += 0.45;
    soustot += 5.95;
  }
  if (option == "escargot") {
    total += 5.32;
    taxes += 0.37;
    soustot += 4.95;
  }

    document.getElementById("taxes").innerHTML = taxes;
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
    document.getElementById("soustotal").innerHTML = soustot;

}
```

I want to return the results in these  tags, but they simply wont return. Also I dont know how to launch the function, I tried with onchange/onload, but nothing is returning!

```
<h3>taxes:</h3><span id="taxes"></span>
<h3>Sous-total:</h3><span id="soustot"></span>
<h3>Total:</h3><span id="total"></span>
```

Thank you for your help

EDIT1: The select option comes from 2 separate menu where lasagna/spaghetti are together and salade/escargot are in another. I need this function to addd both prices and taxes and print it in those h3.

Here are the 2 select menus:

```
<select name="repas" id="entree2" onChange="changerepas(this.value)">
    <option value="hidden1" selected>Choisir...</option>
    <option value="spaghetti">Spaghetti</option>
    <option value="lasagne">Lasagne</option>
  </select>

<select name="entree" id="entree3" onChange="changeit(this.value)">
    <option value="hidden" selected>Choisir...</option>
    <option value="salade">Salade</option>
    <option value="escargot">Escargot</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: hi you got some order code problem and this is impact your application, i did a little change the rest you need to adapt to your context ;) salut.

Answer (score 1):

just a little example based on your, you got some problem on init variable ... regards.

```
document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', function() {
  taxesrepas(this.value);
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OxjjYv

Comment: The thing is, there is 2 select option menu and spaghetti/lasagna are together. Escargot and salade are together. So the function gets its information from choices from 2 different menu.

Comment: we can talk in the chat if you wanted ;) then we can talk in private with your fluent language ;).

Comment: Haha alright, chat me ! im in the javascript chatroom. Et je viens de voir que tu es de france !

Comment: Je nai pas assez de rep pour parler dans le chat lol, est ce que tu as skype ?

Comment: I see you said Hi on chat. mais jai pas 20 de rep alors je peux pas parler lol

Comment: jai 18 rep il me manque 2 lol. Si tu me donnes 2 je vais pouvoir te parler

Comment: ok normalement sa va basculer j'aurais la possiblité de t'inviter

Comment: je te mit un + sa donne quoi?

Comment: donc je fais juste attendre dans le chat ?

Comment: Je suis a 23 maintenant je crois quil faut que sa update je suis toujours bloquer. Sinon trouve moi dans les users et parle moi p-e ?? sinon on attend un peu

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155724/discussion-between-headmax-and-bourki).

Comment: tu n'est toujours pas dans le chat?